# R unable to load dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, rcpp

I'm running from Ubuntu 16, using R version 3.4.1. I have `dplyr` installed and can load it when either I am running from RStudio or when I sudo into R from the terminal. However, if I run R without root permission, I cannot load dplyr due to the following error:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘dplyr’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
unable to load shared object '<user-directory>/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/Rcpp/libs/Rcpp.so':
<user-directory>/anaconda3/lib/R/bin/exec/../../lib/../.././libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by <user-directory>/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/Rcpp/libs/Rcpp.so)
```

(where above I've replaced the `/home/MY_USER_NAME` dir with `<user-directory>` for some mild anonymization). I've seen a couple posts that may be tangentially related, but none of those remedies worked for me.

I'm curious if the fix is something as simple as changing permissions or ownership of certain files, or if the issue is that the search for `GLIBCXX_3.4.20` is directed into my `anaconda3` directory (when not root?!)?

Thank you in advance for any insights!

**Edit**: This may be an issue from a more base level with my installation of R. Often I install packages using `install.packages(...)` within RStudio, but on occasion this results in an error that is overcome by installing with `install.packages(...)` after entering R as root. This was the case with both `dplyr` and `Rcpp`. I.e., the versions which I have just reinstalled were done so as

```
> sudo R
> install.packages( 'Rcpp', dependencies = T )
> install.packages( 'dplyr', dependencies = T )
```

Answer (score 3):

Please make your question useful and understandable by stating *how* you installed these packages.

They come both from Ubuntu ie `sudo apt-get install r-cran-dplyr` will get a working version, and from CRAN ie `install.r dplyr` will too (here using my `install.r` from littler, use other wrappers to `install.packages()` at your leisure).

Sometimes your underlying libraries change so my first bet would be to simply reinstall Rcpp and then dplyr.

Your reference to `/home` suggests you installed from source, but as `root`.  That is a bad idea.  There a number of other questions answered here on the site about when/where/how `apt-get` may (or may not) be preferable so I don't need to repeat this.

*Edit:* In response to your edit:

1. Never ever do `sudo R`. You want to write to `/usr/local/lib/R/site-library` and for that you can 1.a) add yourself to the group owning that directory or 1.b) make it owned by your group if it is just you on that machine.
2. You could just do `install.packages(c("Rcpp", "dplyr"))` but you don't even need that as `dplyr` depends on `Rcpp`.
3. Why not use the prebuild package?  Remove what you have (ie `sudo R CMD  REMOVE Rcpp` and ditto for `dplyr`, then do `sudo apt-get install r-cran-dplyr`